# Can the mount command mount iso files into virtual drives?

Tags: mount, iso

I was looking over some question here on the site. From what I understood I could mount an iso file in a virtual drive using "-o loop" (the loop option). Is this true?

...if it is then I'm having trouble using it. I was trying this:

`sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /media/*username*/VDVD /home/*username*/Desktop/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso`

I'm trying to mount the Ubuntu iso in a virtual drive. I used mount. I specified the type. I used "the loop option. The first directory is where the file would be mounted and the second is the file itself. I get the output `/media/minow/VDVD: Is a directory` ...it's like I wanna tell the terminal "YEAH I KNOW!"

so anyways :D is there something wrong with my command or is it impossible to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it the other way around, first specify the file and then the folder where you want to mount it.

Comment: wow I did it! that wasn't hard!!! XD well thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, you can install gcdemu to get something of a gui to mount isos and bin/cue pairs.

Comment: yes I already have gcdemu and I always use it but I was just asking if mount can do it too. thanks :D